# Excel: How to extract data from two linked columns to third

Tags: excel

Here is my table. I need to match the numbers in columns A and C and extract the linked prices from B to D. Columns A and B are fixed, they are my reference numbers and prices.

Thank you!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVfz6.png

Comment: The link above is going to my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a `VLOOKUP` formula like so:

```
=VLOOKUP(C2,A:B,2,FALSE)
```

Paste that into cell D2 and drag down to autofill the rest.